# Making hidden input for each heading value in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have a div that is properly showing data from the controller in the h3 tag, but I"m trying to map that value into it's own hidden input as well and I'm having an issue

The data is correct so the h3 for each div shows the appropriate data, which is looped by $key. If I do this

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)

    <h3 class="uk-width-4-10">{{$item->category}}</h3>
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_category" id="edit_category" value="{{$item->category}}" />

@endforeach



function editCommentModal(){

    console.log(document.getElementById("edit_category").value);

}
```

Then my console logs without error, but it isn't showing the category for the selected item, obviously due to there not being unique ID/Name on the hidden input.

However, when I add the key to make it unique I get a 'Can't read property 'value' of null.

Here's the new version with the $key causing the error:

```
@foreach($items as $key => $item)

    <h3 class="uk-width-4-10">{{$item->category}}</h3>
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_category_{{ $key }}" id="edit_category_{{ $key }}" value="{{$item->category}}" />

@endforeach



function editCommentModal(){

    console.log(document.getElementById("edit_category_{{ $key }}").value);

}
```

How can I properly make sure that each div has a hidden input matching the shown H3 value?

Comment: `$key` is not defined outside the `foreach`.

Comment: Oh, of course! How should I properly pass that reference in this case?

Comment: @Whisou138 I don't think there's any real great way to do what you want there. It might be a better option to tell us what you are trying to achieve with the code. e.g. Hidden elements are for form posts, but you are also using javascript to reference. A better solution may be available.

Comment: We're building a list that has static text ( which I need to pass in the ajax) but one input that's editable. So if they edit that input, I want to send it to the insert via ajax but need some of the static text (in the headers) for reference in mysq